# Can't telnet to uverse router

Tags: lan, wake-on-lan, wan

I have a standard 3801HGV Uverse router, and I am attempting to configure Wake on WAN for it. I have forwarded port 9 with UDP, WOL works great, and so now I have attempted to send the magic packets from my router. The only problem is, the connection is refused when I attempt to telnet or ssh into 192.168.1.254 as user "admin". The bottom line is, I'm doing something wrong in terms of router configuration, obviously, and I don't know what.

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.254
Trying 192.168.1.254...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

$ telnet -l admin 192.168.1.254
Trying 192.168.1.254...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Telnet and SSH are both TCP services. I don't think the u-Verse gateway has them enabled. Doing so usually mean it will expose a shell or custom server. Neither seem likely for a consumer gateway router.

Setting up WOL on U-verse gateway usually means it will allow you to wake your home device from the internet. You will still need some separate WOL application to generate that WOL packet.

Comment: Wouldn't I need remote access to the broadcast ip in order to wake it over the internet? Even with an application?

Comment: You need remote access to your gateway's public IP. This can be done via DDNS but in the case of uVerse, your public IP almost never change unless you replace the gateway. The WOL application will take care of the rest.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for linux systems? I've used etherwake and wakeonlan but they don't work with WOW, just WOL.